# DataTable search an rename duplicate

Tags: c#

sorry for this noob question, but i dosent found a soultion for this simple problem. :(

In this dt, i want to find in first column duplicates an rename it to "_1", "_2",... .

```
**customer_id**   **shippingname**   **shippingaddress**

100001              John Wayne          John Wayne Street
100001              Billy Jean          Billy Jean Street
100002              John Conner         John Conner Street
100003              John Smith          John Smith Street
100001              Carrol Tree         Carrol Tree
```

final result must look like this:

```
**customer_id**   **shippingname**   **shippingaddress**

100001              John Wayne          John Wayne Street
100001_1            Billy Jean          Billy Jean Street
100002              John Conner         John Conner Street
100003              John Smith          John Smith Street
100001_2            Carrol Tree         Carrol Tree
```

hope i could explain it :).
Thanks so much :).

Comment: You can use [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) in order to find the indices of the duplicated lines, once done you can easily change their index value. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way how to do it...

```
//setting up your table...
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("customer_id", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("shippingname", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("shippingaddress", typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add("100001", "John Wayne", "John Wayne Street");
dt.Rows.Add("100001", "Billy Jean", "Billy Jean Street");
dt.Rows.Add("100002", "John Conner", "John Conner Street");
dt.Rows.Add("100003", "John Smith", "John Smith Street");
dt.Rows.Add("100001", "Carrol Tree", "Carrol Tree");

//table initialized

//first we group our rows by customer_id ... 
var grps = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("customer_id"));

//then we handle each group...
foreach (var grp in grps)
{
    int i = 1;//our suffix counter
    foreach (var row in grp.Skip(1)) // we go through all elements but the first...
    {
        row.SetField("customer_id", $"{grp.Key}_{i++}");//we set the new id
    }
}
```